# Any advantages to using separate databases on single server for a reports module?

Tags: php, mysql, schema

I have a report class that saves data like summary page views, banner impressions and so on. These are mostly INSERT and UPDATE queries. This takes a pounding.
Would it be a good idea to move the tables to a separate database and use a separate connection? Wondering if there would be any major advantages in relation to; performance, scalability etc. Thanks

Comment: speed advantage no, easier to maintain - that's your call your doing the maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only if you are trying to manage load. If there is a lot of inserts and updates going on, that could cause locking issues if your tables are MyISAM. If you are doing replication, then heavy logging can cause slaves to fall behind because mysql replication is serial. You can do 10 inserts simultaneously on 10 different tables, but replication causes them to run one after another. That can cause more important inserts to take longer to replicate.

Having a separate server for logging will help performance and scalability. Keep in mind though that you can't join across servers.

Comment: Thanks Brent, I wasn't at this stage thinking of a separate server just a separate database and different connection on the same server. Tables are MyISAM.

Comment: Ahh, having a separate connection to the same server is really just adding overhead. "databases" are more of a way of grouping tables and doesn't help or hurt performance much. A separate database server will split the load. You can have 2 mysql "servers" running on the same physical server and listening on 2 different ports. Facebook does this because they use SSD drives, which are too fast for a single instance of mysql to tax.